# Octave: warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1286 occurred in init_gl_context

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Every time I try plotting in Octave, I receive this error:

```
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1286 occurred in init_gl_context
warning: called from
    __line__ at line 128 column 1
    line at line 56 column 8
    __plt__>__plt2vv__ at line 502 column 10
    __plt__>__plt2__ at line 248 column 14
    __plt__>__plt1__ at line 207 column 10
    __plt__ at line 119 column 17
    plot at line 223 column 10
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1286 occurred drawing 'line' object
warning: called from
    __plt__ at line 120 column 34
    plot at line 223 column 10
```

I've tried all the different forums with recommendations for how to eliminate these warnings, but they keep appearing. Any recommendations?

Comment: What OS and Octave version? Since this is a GL error I assume you are *NOT* using gnuplot but an OpenGL toolkit like qt or fltk. A workaround may bee switching actually to graphics_toolkit gnuplot or perhaps fix your GPU driver

Comment: I'm having the same error on macOS Sierra and Octave 4.2.1 built from source with `brew install octave --build-from-source`. The command that is giving me this error is `imshow('./path/to/image.jpg');`. @Andy could you reply with your workaround?

Comment: Opened issue here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?50612

Comment: Adding `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");` to `~/.octaverc` seems to work as a workaround

Comment: Alternatively, add `graphics_toolkit("fltk");` to `~/.octaverc`.